# Excel Change Line with " "

Tags: excel

[image]

Like this , How to do sith formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data contains space then try-

```
=MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""),SEQUENCE(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))),1)
```

If there is no space then use-

```
=MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1)
```

Also you can use `FILTERXML()` if characters are space delimated.

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s")
```

[image]

Comment: my excel not have SEQUENCE this keyword .
and 
"  =FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s")  "
it's noly work in B1 , not working in b2 b3 ....

Comment: It's working when I use "Ctrl+Shift+Enter" , thanks ~

Comment: `SEQUENCE()` is available only to `Excel365`. So, for non 365 version of excel need to enter as array formula with `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the Excel Feature "Split Cells"? You should be able to provide a splitting character and select a target region. Not sure if you create a vertical target, but worst case you can split the cells into a horizontal target zone and then transpose the result.

Maybe this link helps:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/merge-split-or-delete-table-cells-d58e60ea-8994-4356-b1ef-5437ea59fd9b